# Converting an Oracle trigger to a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-trigger

I've got this trigger in Oracle and need to convert it to SQL Server but I have no clue about SQL Server .

Maybe someone here knows how to convert this trigger?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_u_gesamtstatus_datum
 BEFORE
  UPDATE
 ON anmeld_x
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.gesamt_status != old.gesamt_status)
begin
  :new.gesamt_status_datum := sysdate;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No but i also don't have the oracle database here on my computer. It is with a colleague and i can't access it. :(

Comment: Two **major** problems: SQL Server doesn't know  `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers, and also `FOR EACH ROW` is not supported by SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You may try below -

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_u_gesamtstatus_datum
ON anmeld_x
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
UPDATE A
SET gesamt_status_datum = CASE WHEN I.gesamt_status <> A.gesamt_status
                                    THEN GETDATE()
                          END
FROM anmeld_x A
INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON I.key_col = A.key_col   -- Here key_col is your primary key column.
```